# Shared Element Transition is broken between three or more activities

Tags: android, android-transitions, shared-element-transition

**Problem**

I want to achieve shared element transition between Activity A and B, and between Activity B and C.

I did everything based on the [android transition documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/start-activity).

There is no problem between:

- A => B => back to A
- A => B and B => C => back to B

But if I do:

- A => B and B => C => back to B => back to A

The last step will not have any shared element transition (actually not only shared element transition, even there is only fading it could be lost).

I have been looking for solutions everywhere, but it seems everybody only needs A => B (and B => A) shared element transition but doesn't care any more transitions from B => C and back to A.

**Example**

See an [example](https://github.com/xiaoyuin/animation-samples/tree/master/ActivitySceneTransitionBasic) I created based on android's animation samples, where Activity A = MainActivity, B = DetailActivity, C = DetailDetailActivity. Clicking the button on Activity B will navigate to Activity C.

[image]

Comment: Hi, can you share what you did already, so that we can find where the problem is ?

Comment: Hi @Walid please see my example repo forked from android animation samples.

Comment: Just to confirm, is the developer option "Don't keep activities" turned off?

Comment: @Cliabhach yes, if that's on you can't even do A -> B -> A.

Comment: same issue, any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Because while executing C => B, it will re-construct a new EnterTransitionCoordinator for B, replacing the old one contains the correct `mPendingExitNames` which it is important to indicate views need to be transitioned between A and B.

```java
public boolean startExitBackTransition(final Activity activity) {
    ArrayList<String> pendingExitNames = getPendingExitNames(); // here
    if (pendingExitNames == null || mCalledExitCoordinator != null) {
        return false;
    } else {
          // ...
     }
}
```

The solution seems to be a little bit tricky. You can refer to [ThreeActivityTransitionDemo](https://github.com/LinZong/ThreeActivityTransition) and pay attention to the `SharedElementUtils`.

Comment: I am getting an exception `java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: No field mPendingExitNames in class Landroid/app/ActivityTransitionState`

Comment: Have you already bypassed Android hidden API restrictions? 
[Restrictions on non-SDK interfaces](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/restrictions-non-sdk-interfaces)
As for my demo provided above, I had imported a dependency `me.weishu:free_reflection:3.0.1` and called `Reflection.unseal(base)` at `ThreeActivityApplication#attachBaseContext` in order to get  'ActivityTransitionState' field in `SharedElementUtils `.

Comment: You were right. I did not notice that. After bypassing restrictions it is working.

Comment: Any luck with solving the issue without reflection?

Comment: No luck, I had updated repo's README for a brief discussion. Use Fragment instead of Activity can easily do it.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to `Activity B`

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.Q && !isFinishing()){
        new Instrumentation().callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(this, new Bundle());
    }
    super.onStop();
}
```

Comment: I can't try your solution since I haven't updated my app to target sdk 30 yet, and I'm trying to find a general solution not only working on android 11

Comment: ok.  does `new Instrumentation().callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(this, new Bundle());` without the version call work on lower sdk?